# How to disable symfony dev mode and profiler in version 3.2.13

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony. I got already developed a Symfony API project for the mobile app, and I can see there is a security issue. The profiler is exposed to outside anyone can check the API request using the URL.

http://hostName/test-api/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/empty/search/results?limit=10

Below is the sign-in API form the mobile app.
http://hostName/test-api/web/app_dev.php/app/sign-in

Can I know how to remove the dev environment and profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not expose the app_dev.php file. This file is used only for dev environment like precised in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#what-is-an-environment).

The environment is defined [here in dev](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/v1.0.0/web/app_dev.php#L31)

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

and [here for prod](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/v1.0.0/web/app.php#L31)

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

So you need to expose your services by exposing the app.php. This way all dev bundles[like the bundles listed on the AppKernel.php](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/v1.0.0/app/AppKernel.php#L32) and configurations will not be loaded

Comment: GrenierJ. Thank you. It has worked I had to do some other change also. Now dev is not accessible to others.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out this issue. Need to uncomment the below code.

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by
// accident to production servers. Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make
// something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```